Python Beginner lesson: end sentence if word repeated
Change the program so that the loop ends also if the user types in the same word twice in a row.
Sample output
Please type in a word: It
Please type in a word: was
Please type in a word: a
Please type in a word: dark
Please type in a word: and
Please type in a word: stormy
Please type in a word: night
Please type in a word: night
It was a dark and stormy night

So this question has two parts. The first part I was able to figure out. 2nd part, not so much. I have added a variable to store the inputted word, but I just can't get it to exit loop when "word == stop"
words = ""
stop = ""
while True: 
    word = input("Please type in a word")
    if word == "end":
        break
    if stop == word:
        break
    words += f"{word} "
print(words)


So with inputs: Hello, my, name, is, end:
I get outputs Hello, my, name, is
This is expected and satisfies question 1. Question 2 wants me to end it if a word is repeated. Above is my attempt that doesn't seem to work. Please no arrays or lists, I know this can be done using that, but as this is a beginner course, and we have not yet learned about those, I am to solve using above methodology.

This question is similar to: How to end whileTrue loop when same input value is put in twice?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I'd do this with a list, appending input to the list, and checking against that list as input is received. Example:
words = []
stop_word = "end"

while True:
    word = input("Please type in a word: ").strip()

    if word == stop_word or (words and word == words[-1]):
        break
    
    words.append(word)

print(" ".join(words))


I'd maybe put stop_word in all caps to indicate that it's a constant? But otherwise, this is about what I'd do too.

You need to update stop after each input so that it contains the last word entered.


words = ""
stop = ""
while True: 
    word = input("Please type in a word: ")
    if word == "end":
        break
    if stop == word:
        break
    words += f"{word} "
    stop = word  # Update the stop variable to the current word
print(words)



The loop will end if the user types "end". It will also end if the user repeats the same words twice in a row. If you are looking forward to doing more python projects, you can try this one using Python and Raspberry pi.
https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/IoT_Using_Raspberry_Pi_and_Python.html
